# How to convert python regex to java regex?

Tags: java, python, regex, regex-negation

I have some regular expressions in Python which I need to convert to java.  I know what I want the regular expression to do, but I just don't know how to convert it.

Here is the expression in python:  `^172\.(1[6789]|2\d|30|31)\.`.  I want it to capture any sort of ip address like `172.X` where X ranges from 16 to 31.

This works in python:

```
import re
pattern='^172\\.(1[6789]|2\\d|30|31)\\.'
test_strings = ['172.19.0.0', '172.24.0.0', '172.45.0.0', '172.19.98.94']
for string in test_strings:
    print re.findall(pattern, string)
```

and it appropriately captures what I expect:

```
['19']
['24']
[]
['19']
```

But I tried to convert these to java and itdoesn't work. It seems like I should be able to convert to a java regex simply by adding a `\` to each `\` to escape correctly?  like `^172\\.(1[6789]|2\\d|30|31)\\.`

but it is still not matching the way I want.  what am I missing about the differences between python and JAVA regular expression in this case?

I do not have the `java` code easily available, but I tried this tool: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/, and I set the Target Text to `172.19.0.0` and it doesn't match, but it does "Find".  However, when I input "blah" as the Target Text it ALSO puts something in the "Find" section...so I'm not sure I trust this tool http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ because it puts any string in "find", even when it is "blah".

So, how do I verify that my java regular expression is correct?

Comment: "but it is still not matching the way I want" can we see how exactly you are using this regex in Java? What is your input, expected and actual result?

Comment: Can we see how it is being used in python too?

Comment: *Guess:* You're using `matches()`. Don't, because that always matches against the *entire* input. Use [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

Comment: @Andreas you mean in java?

Comment: Yes, I mean in Java. That is what you're asking, right? How to do it in Java? And my guess is that you're using the wrong Java method.

Comment: Yes @Andreas that is what I'm asking.  I tried my regular expressions at http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ and it seems to "find" everything and match nothing, whereas in python it correctly finds the things it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 does not have the equivalent of `findall()`, so you need to write your own [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) loop and gather the results into a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), like this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^172\\.(1[6789]|2\\d|30|31)\\.");
String[] test_strings = {"172.19.0.0", "172.24.0.0", "172.45.0.0", "172.19.98.94"};
for (String string : test_strings) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string); matcher.find(); )
        list.add(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

*Output*

```
[19]
[24]
[]
[19]
```

Or course, since your regex can **find at most one match**, your code should really be:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^172\\.(1[6789]|2\\d|30|31)\\.");
String[] test_strings = {"172.19.0.0", "172.24.0.0", "172.45.0.0", "172.19.98.94"};
for (String string : test_strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    else
        System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
19
24

19
```

Comment: I'm not of age to vote, but +1 @Andreas!  Is this true for `scala` as well?

Comment: @jaja You should still be able to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. Sorry, I don't know Scala.